# Get the internet from my PC

Tags: 2.1-eclair, internet, usb-tethering, reverse-tether

I only have Internet connection from LAN through Linux PC.

How can I connect my Android 2.1 to the Internet though USB cable?

Comment: Which phone are you using? Many phone manufacturers provide software which enables [Internet tethering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tethering). I have HTC One X and HTC Sync Manager which allows me to tether my phone to my laptop. But HTC Sync Manager is only available for Windows and I assume it would be case with others also.

Comment: Damn; This isn't a duplicated question. The answer provided as a duplicated from works for Windows ONLY while I'm clearly said that I'm using Linux!!!

Comment: @AlEverett: Please unmark this question as duplicate. This question refer to Linux OS not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If you're rooted you can use this...

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jasongong.tether.usb

There are other apps out there that do the same, but that one looks reliable and is free.

Comment: I think this exactly what I'm looking for but unfortunately it doesn't work although I successfully installed it... BTW: I'm using SonyEricsson Xperia X8